# how to use Always Compile in flashdevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, flashdevelop

Where is this option? how to set the Main.as as Always Compile? The breakpoints and step by step function not work for me...

Answer (score 2):

Open the Project panel (look in View menu if it's hidden), select the desired main class, and:

- **FD3**: Right Click > Always Compile
- **FD4**: Right Click > Set Document Class

Answer (score 0):

In 'project properties' You have tab :'Compiler options' , first put text in 'Link report' option and compile , it will generate XML with compiled classes , than write additional Classes in file and put file in 'Load Externs'. Now compiler will include all classes from XML .