# How to always compile a file?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qml

I have a Qt project with QML files. Whenever I change these files, I have to manually right click the .qrc (resources) file and recompile it.

How do I tell visual studio to *always* compile a certain file, not only when it thinks it has changed?

(Here are similar questions others have asked for [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086869/how-to-always-compile-a-cpp-file-with-eclipse) and [flashdevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758022/how-to-use-always-compile-in-flashdevelop))

Comment: You could use `qmake` and `make` for compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem while building qt apps using Qt Creator.(Especially while using QML files as resources.) I solved the problem using a little hack.

- Created a batch file say touch.bat in my source directory.
- This batch file contains a single line `copy qml.qrc /B+ ,,/Y` where `qml.qrc` is the resource file name.
- Opened my project in QtCreator and went to Project->Build Steps->Add Build Step->Custom process step and entered `touch.bat`
- Whenever the project build starts, the `qml.qrc` is touched. The build system thinks that qml.qrc is modified and builds it.

You can modify this hack for Visual Studio also.(I have not tried). Try adding `touch.bat` as a build step in Visual studio. The idea is to fool the build system to think that your .qrc is modified.

I guess this is a known bug which remains unresolved. Check this [bug report.](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13334)
Thanks.

Comment: This is similar to what I do (I just remove the generated files related to the .qrc file). I'm pretty sure the bug report for this is: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13334. You might want to mention that in your answer.