# QML : mouse hover not working

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have this QML code and its really straight forward but my problem is the onEntered and onExited does not work at all. I do not see anything wrong with the code and I feel it is a QtQuick bug !

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    width: 480
    height: 320
    Rectangle {
        x: 30; y: 30
        width: 300; height: 240
        color: "lightsteelblue"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent

            hoverEnabled: true

            onEntered: {
                console.log('mouse over ya kbeer');
            }

            onExited: {
                console.log('mouse out ya kbeer');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this as a qml component to be used in other place. am not sure but maybe because I have to embed them inside another Qt Quick items the mouse events does not reach this item because it has been cached by the parent am not sure of that !

Any suggestions and help is really appreciated !

Comment: How do you use this rectangle QML item? if you use it inside another QML item, which hover enabled too, then it eats the mouse events first and that's why you don't see any received event.

Comment: yes I use it inside another item, but am not using the mouse hover on the upper item, and its catchs the onClicked but not onEntered

Comment: well, for some reasons the mouse events is not get propagated to your inner element. I suggest you one by one to put MouseArea in parents elements and find out what last parent element receives the mouse event ... and think why it doesn't propagate it.

Comment: I think i found the issues, take a look at my answer if you could help me in that I will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are built into your executable. If you want to change them, you need to rebuild the exe.

You can try add new `QML` file by `Add new - Qt - QML file`: write here your code (using Qt Quick) but load it to your `QQuickView` by `view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("fullpath.qml"));` When you finish your app, write this file to resource and use resource path.

Comment: Why QCreator put them always on resources ? since I have to rebuild each time, is there a way to not do that ?

Comment: @CreativeCoder You can use just .qml file to write code and debug it, but in release, write this .qml file to your exe and use Qt resource system(in this case, nobody can't see your source code and user can't delete it.

Comment: actually, it's you putting qml files as resources. You can use them just as related files to your executable. So, they will be not embedded into the binary. Also it's suggested to develop the QML part first just with using of qml emulator.

Comment: @CreativeCoder it is better then user can delete your qml code and your program will crash, or user will rewrite your qml source as he wants and app will crash again :)

Comment: what I mean by bad is I have to rebuild each time, since I will have huge c++ code and qml both side by side and as you said, I can't keep qml far from resources or the main project since its related to the c++ code.

Comment: @CreativeCoder You can try add new QML file by Add new - Qt - QML file: write here your code (using Qt Quick) but load it to your QQuickView by `view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("fullpath.qml"));` When you finish your app, write this file to resource and use resource path.

Comment: @CreativeCoder in this case I added this advice to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issues is not on the code or qml but on the QCreator itself, when I update my qml code since it is in the resources and when I click on run it does not take the latest update. now after I rebuild it its works fine. But does anyone knows why this happens !

Comment: sometimes QtCreator really doesn't embed modified resource files into the binary, that's why usually I do rebuild when changing qml files.

Comment: is there a way to solve this issues ? I don't want to rebuild each time i update qml file

Comment: if I knew how to avoid this I would not do rebuild :)

Comment: This is a known issue. But you can avoid this. See my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944219/how-to-always-compile-a-file/25945561#25945561